# Can I do this with a Python key logger?

Tags: python, logging, pynput, keylogger

I am working on a python key logger and currently if I were to type "Hello World" it would say

```
'h'
'e'
'l'
'l'
'o'
Key.space
'w'
'o'
'r'
'l'
'd'
```

I would like it to just say `"Hello World"` instead
or at least

```
'hello'
'world'
```

here is my code:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = "mydirectory"

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')


def on_press(key):
    logging.info(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: @KenWhite is it possible that it logs up until I press space, then it logs all that was recorded before space was pressed?

Comment: just collect the values in a list and _then_ log them whenever some space or whatever occurs (you can use `"".join(my_collection)` to assemble a list into a single string) .. beware that listening like may not nicely track backspace `^H` and post-processing it may be more useful

Comment: @ti7 how do I create the "my_collection" string?

Comment: Then make an effort to figure out how.

Comment: @KenWhite that doesn't help me much :|

Comment: What doesn't help you much is having someone tell you what you need to do, making no effort to figure out how to do it, and just coming back and begging for someone to do it for you. You'll never learn anything if you don't make an effort to do the work, except how to depend on copy/pasting the work of others.

Comment: @KenWhite That is a good point, I was mostly just asking if it is possible just so I don't waste my time, thanks though.